# Looping through json received from API

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, parsing

I seem to only get the last entry of lastname.  I have spent all day on this and was wondering if someone can see what I am missing.
Thank you

```
<!doctype html>
<html>

    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Untitled Document</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.2.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function () {
                $.ajax({
                    url: "http://testsite.legisconnect.com/list.php",
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function (data) {
                        $.each(data.response.legislators, function (i, item) {
                            $('#here').html(item.legislator.lastname);
                        });
                    }
                });
            });
        </script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="here"></div>
    </body>

</html>
```

JSON

```
{
    "response": {
        "legislators": [{
            "legislator": {
                "website": "http://ackerman.house.gov/",
                "fax": "202-225-1589",
                "govtrack_id": "400003",
                "firstname": "Gary",
                "chamber": "house",
                "middlename": "L.",
                "lastname": "Ackerman",
                "congress_office": "2111 Rayburn House Office Building",
                "eventful_id": "",
                "phone": "202-225-2601",
                "webform": "http://www.house.gov/writerep",
                "youtube_url": "http://www.youtube.com/RepAckerman",
                "nickname": "",
                "gender": "M",
                "district": "5",
                "title": "Rep",
                "congresspedia_url": "http://www.opencongress.org/wiki/Gary_Ackerman",
                "in_office": true,
                "senate_class": "",
                "name_suffix": "",
                "twitter_id": "repgaryackerman",
                "birthdate": "1942-11-19",
                "bioguide_id": "A000022",
                "fec_id": "H4NY07011",
                "state": "NY",
                "crp_id": "N00001143",
                "official_rss": "",
                "facebook_id": "RepAcherman",
                "party": "D",
                "email": "",
                "votesmart_id": "26970"
            }
        }, {
            "legislator": {
                "website": "http://adams.house.gov/",
                "fax": "202-226-6299",
                "govtrack_id": "412414",
                "firstname": "Sandra",
                "chamber": "house",
                "middlename": "",
                "lastname": "Adams",
                "congress_office": "216 Cannon House Office Building",
                "eventful_id": "",
                "phone": "202-225-2706",
                "webform": "",
                "youtube_url": "http://www.youtube.com/RepSandyAdams",
                "nickname": "",
                "gender": "F",
                "district": "24",
                "title": "Rep",
                "congresspedia_url": "http://www.opencongress.org/wiki/Sandy_Adams",
                "in_office": true,
                "senate_class": "",
                "name_suffix": "",
                "twitter_id": "RepSandyAdams",
                "birthdate": "1956-12-14",
                "bioguide_id": "A000366",
                "fec_id": "H0FL24049",
                "state": "FL",
                "crp_id": "N00030926",
                "official_rss": "",
                "facebook_id": "",
                "party": "R",
                "email": "",
                "votesmart_id": "31041"
            }
        }, {
            "legislator": {
                "website": "http://aderholt.house.gov/",
                "fax": "202-225-5587",
                "govtrack_id": "400004",
                "firstname": "Robert",
                "chamber": "house",
                "middlename": "B.",
                "lastname": "Aderholt",
                "congress_office": "2264 Rayburn House Office Building",
                "eventful_id": "",
                "phone": "202-225-4876",
                "webform": "http://aderholt.house.gov/?sectionid=195&sectiontree=195",
                "youtube_url": "http://www.youtube.com/RobertAderholt",
                "nickname": "",
                "gender": "M",
                "district": "4",
                "title": "Rep",
                "congresspedia_url": "http://www.opencongress.org/wiki/Robert_Aderholt",
                "in_office": true,
                "senate_class": "",
                "name_suffix": "",
                "twitter_id": "Robert_Aderholt",
                "birthdate": "1965-07-22",
                "bioguide_id": "A000055",
                "fec_id": "H6AL04098",
                "state": "AL",
                "crp_id": "N00003028",
                "official_rss": "",
                "facebook_id": "RobertAderholt",
                "party": "R",
                "email": "",
                "votesmart_id": "441"
            }
        }]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your success handler, you're looping through the collection and replacing the innerHTML each time with a new entry.

```
               success: function (data) {
                    $.each(data.response.legislators, function (i, item) {
                        $('#here').html(item.legislator.lastname);
                    });
                }
```

Thus, when you reach the end of the loop, only the most recent lastname is inserted, as all of the others have been repeatedly replaced.

Did you mean to append, as in the example below?  Or perhaps insert the name in a different element each time?

```
               success: function (data) {
                    $.each(data.response.legislators, function (i, item) {
                        $('#here').append('<span>' + item.legislator.lastname + '</span>');
                    });
                }
```

Comment: I love you... I literally love you.

Answer (score 4):

By using [`.html()`](http://api.jquery.com/html/) with every iteration, you're overwriting your results. Thus, only the last entry is being displayed. Try with [`.append()`](http://api.jquery.com/append/) instead.